# Toast Notification Placement

Tags: notification, toast

I'm working on a platform that should display Success and Error notifications when the user performs certain actions.

Initially we thought about placing the notifications in the top right corner, but we realized that they would hide part of the top-bar actions menu.

My first thought was to change the position of the [toasts](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_snackbar.asp) to the bottom right corner, but some colleagues think they would be more visible down the center.

I was wondering if there is a consensus, or default place to place these notifications, or if there are reasons to avoid placing them somewhere specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends. If the actions being performed are crucial and users must know if their actions have successfully been completed or failed, positioning them in the centre is the best way. However, in any other case, positioning them in 'the bottom right corner' is your answer. The reason is users are familiar with notifications appearing in the bottom right corner, and they will get instantly noticed by the user. Windows notifications always appear in the bottom right corner is also one of the reasons to consider positioning them there. [image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your interface layout and the priority of the messaging. For example, if you have left navigation and properties area to the right, choose the bottom centre (like Figma does) where there is more 'clear' space.

I have reviewed multiple Design System Libraries where they allow the notification to be placed in numerous locations (that wouldn't be great for consistency if you used them all, but it does point to there not being a solid standard). Windows uses bottom right, and Apple use top right (Left to right languages - My assumption is these both switch sides for Right to Left languages, too (something you wouldn't have to worry about with central alignment and if you support R2L)

Users will generally recognise a change in the page; if animated, the movement will draw extra focus. You should also ensure your messages are announced for Screen Reader users who may not see the notification.

If you follow the 'F' pattern for assumed reading of the page, then importance might determine your placement. If it's "User created successfully", then somewhere towards the bottom (left, centre or right) is most appropriate.